# Top widget not appearing on Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am currently doing a Flutter web project wherein I'm trying to replicate the UI of the Ubuntu desktop. Currently using this picture as a reference.

[image]

For the background image I used a `container` widget with an `AssetImage` widget as shown by the codeblock below.

```
class UbuntuBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  const UbuntuBackground({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/ubuntu.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I made a *toy* `Sidebar` widget with a `column` widget containing 2 `container` widgets.

```
class AppSidebar extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppSidebar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static Color sidebarColor = Color(0xff0D486E);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: sidebarColor,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I then thought of using the `Stack` widget in order to have the `AppSidebar` show in front of the `UbuntuBackground` widget.

```
class UbuntuHomepage extends StatefulWidget {
  UbuntuHomepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UbuntuHomepageState createState() => _UbuntuHomepageState();
}

class _UbuntuHomepageState extends State<UbuntuHomepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AppSidebar(),
        UbuntuBackground(),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

The `UbuntuHomepage` is also the app's default route as specified in my `main.dart` file.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Ubuntu',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: UbuntuHomepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

However, building the app will only show the `UbuntuBackground` widget as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

With that, how can I overlay the `AppSidebar` widget over the `UbuntuBackground` widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppSidebar() is under the background, Instead, try like this,

```
return Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, children: <Widget>[
      UbuntuBackground(),
      AppSidebar(),
    ]);
```

In Stack, the last widget will be the top widget.